# Iptable rules through two firewalls for an rdp connection

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, firewall, iptables, nat

[image]

Suppose I have a network topology similar to the one above, if i wanted to rdp into a host on the private network from home these are the following iptable rules i have:

Firewall 1:

$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --source **HOME** --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination **WORK**

$IPT -A FORWARD -p tcp -d **WORK** --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT

Firewall 2:

What rules would i add here? Would it just be a forwarding rule or do i need to add some more NAT stuff?